# Running A Webcam 600ft underwater

Tags: transmission-line

I doing a bit of research into the concept of using webcams to watch crab and fish traps to solve the problem of hauling up empty traps.

Depth 100 fathoms = 600 feet.  Obviously wireless won't work. It also has to be cheap because the fishing gods like holding onto your gear at regular intervals - and seemingly the more expensive your gear the more they like holding onto it.

Q1: Is there a standard that is intended for this scenario?

Failing an applicable standard I am thinking a couple of DSL line drivers - essentially a home made DSL modem on either end of twisted pair with power provided by an AC signal down the same line that I rectify back to DC.

Essentially it would look like a 600ft telephone line that I can map to USB at each end allowing cheap off the shelf USB cameras to be used.

Q2: Is there some obvious concept I am missing with the latter?

Comment: Salt water ... 600 feet ... dark ... cold ... under pressure ... battery powered? ... I can't help but it sounds like a big hammer to crack a nut. Is there no other way to detect empty/non-empty traps? Camera seems overkill.

Comment: Low light conditions, swirling sandy debris obscuring vision, seaweed issues....

Comment: If you are willing to ditch USB, you can buy PoE (power over ethernet) IP cameras. 200 m should not be a problem for the signals, and you would be able to power the camera over the same cable. The waterproofing part is not going to be easy in any case.

Comment: @Roger also additional benefit of seeing if there are any crabs in the area on the way down

Comment: @BrentonThomas It will still be dark, and I'm no fisherman but do crabs swim or are they just crawling on the bottom anyway? No harm trying, it just sounds like you're opening a can of worms.

Comment: [This commercial camera](http://www.seaviewer.com/underwater_video_cameras_sea_drop_kit_options.html) seems to suggest that cheap webcams wouldn't be up to working at that sort of depth. However, it may give you some pointers.

Comment: This is one of those things that can be done, but is terribly non-economic to do, especially after you break a few - the sea is not kind to electronics, and trap-hauling isn't either. Look at ROVs for examples of the tech (underwater camera and lights side, and data transmission to the surface) - if you are going to put one on each trap, you're essentially parking 80% of an ROV on each trap. You might, in fact, want to start with one low-end ROV to get some idea about the tech you'll need, and also to see what you do see.

Answer (score 3):

USB over 600 feet is a no-go, at least directly. USB2 uses a 480 Mb/sec data rate, so DSL/ADSL, with a 9 Mb/sec, is not going to work. 100baseT Ethernet has a nominal max cable length of 100 m between routers/switches, so you'd need a box halfway down your cable. Plus, you need considerable extra cable length to keep the cosine law of tension from causing your camera to walk. For 600 feet, anchored at the seabed, I'd recommend counting on a 1000 foot cable.

I'd suggest your best bet for video transmission is fiber optic. Deepwater ROVs do this routinely, so it's clearly possible. By commercial standards your 600 foot depth is modest, so it's technically feasible, but starting from scratch as a complete noob to the field will make things difficult. You'll need a fiber connector which operates at 300 psi, and those are not, so far as I know, an off-the-shelf item.

Comment: I think the bottom end fiber is likely to just be potted in place (rather than have a 300 PSI connector,) but even that can be trickier than it seems to get right.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Yeah, especially at 300 psi. I'd worry about seawater infiltrating between the core and the jacket, so the cable is probably pricey.

Comment: I was thinking of mapping the USB to something else perhaps ethernet using something like an ASIX AX88772ALF USB to Ethernet bridge and then feed the output of that into a vDSL line driver. When it gets to the other end reverse the process and use the twisted pair as a transmission line to provide power as well. Essentially it would be the meaty bits of a DSLAM to DSL Modem to USB circuit.  DSLAMs are expensive - but they are telco grade with all the network management interfaces. The whole lot would be "potted" in a transparent acrylic ball or case.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question.
When i wanted to build my ROV i had the same trouble.

The best solution is to use ethernet.
If you don't care about lag and just want to use usb cameras then using a 
**Raspberry pi and gstreamer software will work**.
If you need low lag then i recommend you look into usb/ip that is sending the usb data packets over ethernet.

The one i really recommend is Virtualhere usb software.The server runs on a SBC like the raspberry pi and the client runs on your pc.
The orange pi plus 2e is also good for this as it has a gigabit ethernet port.
If you could clarify what requirements you have and the usb camera model maybe i can help.